# Radio buttons group with both options enabled

Tags: java, radio-button

I already made a button group for gender, but still both radio buttons were being enabled. I tried interchanging the group of gender to yearlevel. The yearlevel does fine and still the gender both radio buttons being enabled.

here's my code:

```
public class myFirstGUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel lblyl = new JLabel("Year Level:");
    JLabel lblCourse = new JLabel("Course:");
    JLabel lblProg = new JLabel("Program:");
    JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender:"); //Gender
    JTextField txtName = new JTextField();
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
    GridBagLayout gLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    JComboBox cboProgram = new JComboBox();
    JRadioButton rbtn1 = new JRadioButton("1st");
    JRadioButton rbtn2 = new JRadioButton("2nd");
    JRadioButton rbtn3 = new JRadioButton("3rd");
    JRadioButton rbtn4 = new JRadioButton("4th");
    JRadioButton rbtn5 = new JRadioButton("5th");
    JRadioButton rbtnM = new JRadioButton("Male"); //Gender Male
    JRadioButton rbtnF = new JRadioButton("Female"); //Gender Female
    JCheckBox chk003a = new JCheckBox("ITE003A");
    JCheckBox chk003 = new JCheckBox("CPE003");
    JCheckBox chk201 = new JCheckBox("CS201");
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup();

    public void setYearLevel() {
        bg1.add(rbtn1);
        bg1.add(rbtn2);
        bg1.add(rbtn3);
        bg1.add(rbtn4);
        bg1.add(rbtn5);
    }

    public void setGender() { //Gender
        bg.add(rbtnM);
        bg.add(rbtnF);
    }

    public void setProgram() {
        cboProgram.addItem("CPE");
        cboProgram.addItem("IE");
        cboProgram.addItem("ECE");
    }

    public myFirstGUI() {
        setYearLevel();
        setProgram();
        setSize(300, 500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setTitle("My First GUI");
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(gLayout);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.ipadx = 10;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(txtName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(lblGender, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(rbtnM, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(rbtnF, gbc);

        rbtnM.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        rbtnF.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(lblProg, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(cboProgram, gbc);

        chk003a.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        chk003.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        chk201.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(lblCourse, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(chk003a, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(chk003, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(chk201, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(lblyl, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(rbtn1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 8;
        panel.add(rbtn2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 9;
        panel.add(rbtn3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        panel.add(rbtn4, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 11;
        panel.add(rbtn5, gbc);

        rbtn1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        rbtn2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        rbtn3.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        rbtn4.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        rbtn5.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 12;
        panel.add(btnReset, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 12;
        panel.add(btnSubmit, gbc);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFirstGUI.this, "Welcome " + txtName.getText() +
                    "\nProgram " + cboProgram.getSelectedItem() +
                    "\nYear Level: " + getYL());
            }

        });

        btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtName.setText("");
                bg.clearSelection();
                bg1.clearSelection();
                cboProgram.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
    }
    public String getYL() {
        if (rbtn1.isSelected())
            return "1st";
        else if (rbtn2.isSelected())
            return "2nd";
        else if (rbtn3.isSelected())
            return "3rd";
        else if (rbtn4.isSelected())
            return "4th";
        else if (rbtn5.isSelected())
            return "5th";
        else
            return "Please select your level";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new myFirstGUI().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want to do, but you can enable/disable elements using `java.awt.Component.setEnabled(boolean)`.

Comment: side note about "myFirstGUI": if you're just about to learn about GUIs in Java, then consider JavaFX instead of Swing as Swing is in maintenance mode and JavaFX is the designated successor.

Comment: @Juriel Take a look at my solution, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Puce will try JavaFX. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have pasted an incomplete code here or not as I Don't see a call to setGender() function from your program. Since the radio buttons are not assigned to the button group, that can cause the problem.

Comment: Yup. There were no setGender() Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why your **JRadioButton** for Male are Female are both being selected, this is what you can do.

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(btnM);
group.add(btnF);
```

You need to group the radio buttons which belong to the same category (group).
After adding them to a group, only one **JRadioButton** will be selected.

Comment: I did bro. it is named bg1. the reason why both enable is because i dont have a setGender(). Thanks for the solution :)